Querying multiple parquet files in a range using duckdb
I have parquet files arranged in this format
/db/{year}/table{date}.parquet
In each year folder, there are up to 365 files.
If I want to query data from a time range, say the week 2024-04-28 to 2024-05-04, I could use
SELECT
  count(*) as count,
FROM read_parquet('/db/2024/table*.parquet')
WHERE date >= '2024-04-28' and date < '2024-05-05'

But I don't need to read all files in /db/2024/table*.parquet. I know exactly which seven files has the data I need. How do I define this in duckdb? I am using Python. I could do my own filtering and put all the files in a Python list like filenames.

you can pass python list into duckdb query:
import json

files = json.dumps(["df1.parquet", "df3.parquet"])

duckdb.sql(f"""select * from read_parquet({files});""")


Assuming that your files are named like this:
table20240428.parquet

and so on, this should work:
SELECT count(*) AS count
FROM read_parquet(
  list_transform(
    generate_series('2024-05-04'::DATE - 6, '2024-05-04'::DATE , interval '1' day),
    n -> '/db/' || strftime(n, '%Y') || '/table' || strftime(n, '%Y%m%d') || '.parquet'
  )
)
;

If your {date} is different, you can just adjust the strftime function.
